# Can I find out who called a zsh script?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, zsh

Assume a script master.sh, which is called as

```
./foo/bar/master.sh
```

and contains the lines

```
#!/bin/zsh
. ./x/y/slave.sh
```

Is it possible to find out **from within slave.sh**, that the script which is doing the sourcing, is *./foo/bar/master.sh* ?

I can not use $0 here, because this would return *./x/y/slave.sh*.

I'm using zsh 5.0.6

Answer (score 0):

one way you can achieve this is that for the child script to take as optional argument the name of the caller. Thus this would be accessible with `$1``
ex:

```
#!/bin/zsh 
# master/leader
. ./x/y/slave.sh $0 # or hardcoded path
```

```
#!/bin/zsh 
# slave/worker
echo "Here is my master $1"
```

(you can also do another custom protocol using a environment variable set by the master)

(this solution would also works on bash, and other shell)

Comment: Well, that's what I am actually doing now, and I do in slave a ${1?parameter missing}, just in case I forgot to pass the parameter, but this is certainly not a nice solution. I had hoped, that zsh - with all the bells and whistles it has - would offer a nice solution for this problem. After all, the sourcing occurs in the same process as the master script, so from the zsh implementation viewpoint, it should be trivial to offer this piece of information.

Comment: @user1934428 I'm not sure if this feature exists (I certainly haven't exhausted zsh's documentation, as I have done with bash), but "from the zsh implementation viewpoint, it should be trivial to offer this piece of information" doesn't mean it should be implemented. Different people want different seemingly "trivial" things at different times, sometimes because they are trying to solve the wrong problem anyway. If all those wishes are granted, the language would have been a horrible mess.

Comment: I meant (but did not say so explicitly) "it should be trivial to implement it and would be IMO valuable for quite a few purposes". I now also think that, as you said, this feature simply doesn't exist (yet). I'll file a feature request at zsh. Perhaps it is considered useful enough to be implemented in a future version.

Answer (score 0):

The information can already be obtained in zsh right now (thanks to Bart Schaefer, who pointed out to me the existence of the variable functrace in the zsh/parameter module):

```
#!/bin/zsh 
# slave/worker
zmodload zsh/parameter
echo "Here is my master ${functrace[$#functrace]%:*}"
```

The '%:*' is necessary, because the entries in the functrace array also contain the line number of the call.